# Python: Headless mode picks up the older version of chrome

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, google-voice

I am trying to automate sending a text message using python & selenium from `https://voice.google.com/about`. When I run below code, it picks up the lattest version/ instance of google chrome and works fine. But, when I run it headless mode, it uses an older version of google chrome(guessing from screenshot) and gives `TimeoutException()` exception. It fails while logging in.

I checked an element id of sign in box in an IE emulator and it appears to be the same.

```
        url = "https://voice.google.com/about"
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.get_screenshot_as_file('C:\\Drivers\\Q11-0.png')

        # Click on a GET GOOGLE VOICE
        WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="heroToggle"]/button/span'))).click()

        print("Clicked on a get google voice")

        # Click on a WEB
        WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="heroToggle"]/div/button[3]'))).click()
        print("Clicked on a WEB button.")

        driver.get_screenshot_as_file('C:\\Drivers\\Q11-1.png')

        # Enter username and password
        # THIS IS WHERE IT FAILS
        WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'identifierId')))
        email = driver.find_element_by_id('identifierId')
        time.sleep(10)
        email.send_keys('username')
        time.sleep(10)
        nextBtn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierNext"]/content/span')
        nextBtn.click()

        driver.get_screenshot_as_file('C:\\Drivers\\Q11-2.png')


        # Enter password
        password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
        password.send_keys('password')
        nextBtn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="passwordNext"]/content')
        nextBtn.click()
```

Screenshot when I run in normal mode,
[image]

Screenshot when I run in headless mode,
[image]

Drivers are updated properly.
I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: When using headless, agent footprint contains tag indicating that this is headless browser. Google can detect this and give you an different version of the website? How did you confirm its using an old chrome version?

Comment: @Infern0, from the screenshot. I am just guessing.

Comment: @Infern0 _...agent footprint contains tag indicating that this is headless browser. Google can detect this and give you an different version of the website..._ source/documentation?

Comment: @DebanjanB i put a questionmark at the end of sentence.

Comment: @PRK You spoke about _picks up the latest version/ instance_ and _headless mode, it uses an older version of google chrome_ but you haven't shown us the driver initialization.

Answer (score 5):

Try to override user-agent, so it wont contains headless tag.

```
opts = Options()
opts.add_argument("user-agent=User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opts)
```