# Why does Chrome load old Gmail Sign-in page in headless mode

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome-headless

I have written  a Gmail sign-in script using selenium-python.
When i run in the script in firefox headless mode, then the script works fine, without any issues.
But, when i run the same script in chrome headless mode, then the script fails.
I then added screenshots in my code for debugging.

While running in firefox headless mode, the **new** Gmail Signin UI is displayed [image: firefox headless]
While running in chrome headless mode, the **old** Gmail Signin UI is displayed [image: chrome headless]
While in chrome headless mode, selenium fails to find the next button with xpath "//div[@id='identifierNext']", since this xpath is of the next button of the new UI.

However, when i run chrome in non-headless mode, then the new Gmail Signin UI is displayed and the scripts does not fail.

I fail to understand, why the old Gmail Signin UI is displayed in chrome headless mode.
Below is the code, (firefox code is commented since i am having issues in only chrome)

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path="C:\\chromedriver.exe")

    # from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
    # firefox_options = Options()
    # firefox_options.headless = True
    # driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=firefox_options,executable_path='C:\\geckodriver.exe')

    driver.get("https://www.google.com")
    print(driver.title)

    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='Sign in']").click()
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file("screenshot1.png")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='email']").send_keys("abcd")
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file("screenshot2.png")
    self.wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='identifierNext']"))).click()
```

If anyone has an explanation for this, kindly let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Look at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53828421/python-headless-mode-picks-up-the-older-version-of-chrome?rq=1). It worked for me.

Comment: @cpuser: thanks for the link, that indeed was the issue :)