# How can I force my program to use an updated version of Google-Chrome when using it in headless mode?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, headless

I have a Python script which uses Google Chrome to perform some tasks in YouTube Studio. The script works as expected when I disable:

`options.add_argument('--headless')`

but when I use it with the headless option it's unable to find some elements, so I decided to take a screenshot to see what was going on.

[image]

It looks like, for some reason, when I use the headless mode, the executed Chrome version is older.

I have also tried to change the user agent: options.add_argument("--user-agent=User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36"), but it doesn't work.

How can I execute an updated version of Chrome using headless mode?

Comment: "Chrome/69.0.3497.100" chrome 69 its quite old version :) try with something newer in the user-agent flag

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Headless mode picks up the older version of chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53828421/python-headless-mode-picks-up-the-older-version-of-chrome)

Comment: @Infern0 your solution worked. You can post it as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested the problem was in the user agent version.

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36
```

From the agent info we can see the chrome version is:

> Chrome/69.0.3497.100

which is quite old version of chrome.

Try with newer version example:

> Chrome/105.0.0.0

Simplest way to fetch actual version is from your browser.
Open new tab, click F12 or inspect - view page source,
Navigate to Network tab, Open some site ex: google.com, check some of the network requests. Select one of the requests until you see: "Request Headers" with the actual to your browser user-agent information.